# Line ending issue with Mercurial or Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, mercurial

I seem to have a strange issue caused by either Visual Studio or Mercurial. This is localised to a single project, so I'm guessing something in the project configuration is causing an issue.

At a difficult to specify point, when I perform an action in Visual Studio, it will update every line ending in the given file, which means that when I look at the file in Sourcetree, every line has changed.

I can replicate this by using NuGet to add a package dependency; the packages.config will be entirely replaced. Even if I then commit all the changes, including line endings, later the same issue will occur. The only workaround I have is to shelve my changes and reapply them, whereupon the lines are written correctly.

I'm not sure which application is to blame here. I did make the mistake of allowing SourceTree to change my Mercurial configuration, an issue that I have now fixed, but I'm not sure if something from that has persisted.

I thought it might be an issue with my Mercurial.ini files or HGrcs but they don't seem to contain anything untoward. Here's my mercurial.ini

```
[ui]
username = ....

[auth]
bb.prefix = https://bitbucket.org/
bb.username = ....
bb.password = ....


[extensions]
mq = 
rebase = 

[web]
allow_push = *
push_ssl = false
```

... and my project hgrc: ...

```
[paths]
default = https://...
```

Answer (score 0):

You have badly configured EOL extension for (single?) repository in Mercurial. Configure it in proper way (or just disable, if your code /repositories/ live only on Windows)

Comment: Good idea, but I don't seem to have the EOL extension enabled. I have modified my question to show my hgrc.